# C# Linq - Delayed Execution

Tags: c#, linq

If I build a query say:

(the query is build using XDocument class from System.Xml.Linq)

```
var elements = from e in calendarDocument.Root.Elements("elementName") select e;
```

and then I call elements.Last() SEVERAL times. Will each call return the most up to date Last() element?

For example if I do

```
elements.Last().AddAfterSelf(new XElement("elementName", "someValue1"));
elements.Last().AddAfterSelf(new XElement("elementName", "someValue2"));
elements.Last().AddAfterSelf(new XElement("elementName", "someValue3"));
elements.Last().AddAfterSelf(new XElement("elementName", "someValue4"));
```

Is it actually getting the latest element each time and added a new one to the end or is elements.Last() the same element each time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, linq queries are lazy evaluated. It's not until you call `Last()` that the query will be executed. In this case it will get the most up to date last element each time.

I think that this actually is the first time I've seen a proper use of calling `Last()` (or any other operator that executes the query) several times. When people do it, it is usually by mistake causing bad performance.

I think that the linq-to-xml library is smart enough to get good performance for your query, but I wouldn't trust it without trying.

Comment: Anders, Thank you. One more thing if you don't mind.. How can I make var elements a global variable? Since I build the query just one time I would like to initialize it and be able to call elements.Last() from anywhere else in my code. Is this possible?

Comment: That's a new and separate question. Please post it as another question (after you've mad an attempt to find the answer yourself and have tried to search SO for old questions). Asking a question here will probably not give much help, as the question is marked as solved no people will look at it.